# TPM passwordless boot

Tags: linux, boot, centos, luks, tpm

I'm trying to create device with CentOS6, encrypted disk (with LUKS), TPM module and [TrustedGRUB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trustedgrub/) to boot securely and without interaction. I'm following instructions from https://github.com/shpedoikal/tpm-luks but i'm still being asked for password (now to access to TPM module's NV memory. That makes the whole thing pointless. Am i doing something wrong or it's that way by design?

I've altered tpm-luks scripts to change NV read/write permissions (to PPREAD|PPWRITE) but it (obviously) didn't help.

I cannot find any clue on the Internet. TPM is very new thing to me, so i'm maybe looking in wrong direction, so any help will be appreciated.